# MongoDB : Search on multiple keys on embeds documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've a Translation document embeds many Translation Locales documents :

```
class Translation
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :key, :type => String
  embeds_many :locales, :class_name => 'TranslationLocale'
end

class TranslationLocale
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :translation

  field :code,  :type => String
  field :state, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :text,  :type => String
end
```

I want to be able to find all Translation documents including a particular locale in a given state.

```
Translation.where('locales.code' => 'en', 'locales.state' => false).all
```

The problem is that query will look for Translation documents embedding a locale with code=en and a locale with state=false but not necessarily on the same sub document.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Translation.where(:locales.matches => {:code=> 'en', :state=> false}).all
```

Example from [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where)

Comment: You rock ! I don't know how I've missed that in the doc. I had tried a similar syntax but without the 'matches' keyword...